# What is the difference between using var and this, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

What is the difference between these?

```
var a = 13;  
this.b = 21;  
document.write(a);  
document.write(b);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For global code (code that is not part of any function), they are *almost* equivalent, both at the end create a property on the global object.

The difference is that `a`, which has been declared with the `var` statement, the [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) process will use the global object as the *Variable Object* <sup>(1)</sup>, and it will define that property as non-deleteable on it, e.g.:

```
var a = 13;
delete a; // false
typeof a; // "number"
```

Then, `b` since the `this` value in global code, points to the global object itself, will be also a *global property*, but this one can be deleted:

```
this.b = 21;
delete b; // true
typeof b; // "undefined"
```

<sub>Don't try the first snippet in Firebug, since the Firebug's console runs the code internally with `eval`, and in this execution context the variable instantiation process behaves differently, you can try it [here](http://jsbin.com/ugehe3/2/).</sub>

<sub>(1)</sub> The Variable Object (VO) is an object that is used by the variable instantiation process to define the identifiers of FunctionDeclarations, identifiers declared with the `var` statements, and identifiers of function formal parameters, in the different [execution contexts](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10), all those identifiers are bound as properties of the VO, the Scope chain is formed of a list of VO's.

For global code, the VO is the global object itself, that's why `a` ends being a property of it. For function code, the VO (*also known as the [Activation Object](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.6) for FunctionCode*), is a new object is created behind the scenes when you invoke a function, and that is what creates a new lexical scope, in short I'll talk about functions.

Both `a` and `this.b` can be [resolved](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.4) simply as by `a` and `b` because the first object in the scope chain, is again the global object.

Also, I think is work knowing that the Variable Instantiation process takes place *before* than the code execution, for example:

```
alert(a); // undefined, it exists but has no value assigned to it yet
alert(b); // ReferenceError is thrown

var a = 13;
this.b = 21;
```

These differences may be trivial but I think is worth knowing them.

Now, if the code snippet you posted is within a function, it is *completely different*.

The `a` identifier, declared with the `var` statement in your example will be a *local variable*, available only to the lexical scope of the function (and any nested functions).

Keep in mind that in JavaScript blocks don't introduce a new scope, only functions do, and to declare a variable in that scope, you should *always* use `var`.

The `this.b` identifier will become a property bound to the object that is referred by the `this` value, but... *What is `this`???*.

The `this` value in JavaScript is implicitly set when you call a function, it is determined by how do you invoke it:

1. When you use the `new` operator, the `this` value inside the function, will point to a newly created object, e.g.:

   ```
   function Test() {
     this.foo = "bar";
   }
   var obj = new Test(); // a new object with a `foo` property
   ```
2. When you call a function that is *member* of an object, the `this` value inside that function will point to the *base object*, e.g.:

   ```
   var obj = {
     foo: function () {
       return this == obj;
     }
   };
   obj.foo(); // true
   ```
3. When you invoke a function without any base object, the `this` value will refer to the global object:

   ```
   function test() {
     return this == window;
   }
   test(); // true
   ```
4. The `this` value can be set explicitly, when you invoke a function using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply):

   ```
   function test() {
     alert(this);
   }
   test.call("hello world!"); // alerts "hello world!"
   ```

Comment: +1 Just for this clear explanation, I checked your profile to see if you had a blog that I could read :)

Comment: +1 for a good explanation, but your first line is somewhat inaccurate: a global variable is not the same thing as a property of the global object, as you then go on to show. That declaring a variable with `var` in the global scope creates a property of the global object is a *side-effect* of the fact that the global object is used as the Variable object in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

To understand in short, if you use these in a function then -

```
this.a; //will create a public property

var b; //will create a member variable
```

e.g. here is a Student class in javascript

```
var Student = function()
{
    // Member variable
    var studentId;

    // Public property
    this.Name = "";
}
```

for more - See [Object Oriented Programming with JavaScript](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/object_oriented_programming_with_javascript__timer_class.aspx)